# Which is the recommended library for Active Directory Authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to perform AD authentication through an Azure microservice. I read about ADAL and GraphAPI. I am confused about the difference between the two.

Which is recommended?

I found couple of samples of GraphAPI but not many samples using ADAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ADAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet) is a library that is used for authentication against Azure Active Directory and Windows Server Active Directory. There are a lot of samples [here](https://github.com/azure-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=active-directory-dotnet).

The [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) is much more.
In addition to performing authentication, it provides API access to a lot of Office 365 services.

Comment: "here" link is not available

Comment: sorry @RKh - it's there now

Comment: Just to add @RKh, here's the [Azure AD Developer Docs](https://aka.ms/aaddev) which has guidance on best practices and examples to help you get going.